# How to Compare Data from Excel Sheet Using Coded UI?

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

How to compare that given data is present in Excel sheet or not using coded UI

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I would not recommend using coded UI for just this task.  Simply open the workbook using an excel library and traverse it programatically.